# Parsing JTextField to Integer

Tags: java

I don't know what's wrong with the code. Can you guys help me out?

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(aTextField.getText());
int b = Integer.parseInt(bTextField.getText());
int c = Integer.parseInt(cTextField.getText());
int discriminant = (int)Math.pow((double)b, 2) - 4*a*c;
int x1 = (int)(-b + (double)Math.sqrt(discriminant) / 2*a);
int x2 = (int)(-b - (double)Math.sqrt(discriminant) / 2*a);

public DiscriminantSoft(){
    super("Quadratic Equation");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    headerLabel = new JLabel("ax^2 + bx + c = 0");
    headerLabel.setToolTipText("You have to write a, b and c in order to calculate discriminant.");
    add(headerLabel);

    aTextField = new JTextField(3);
    add(aTextField);
    bTextField = new JTextField(3);
    add(bTextField);
    cTextField = new JTextField(3);
    add(cTextField);

    thehandler handler = new thehandler();
    aTextField.addActionListener(handler);
    bTextField.addActionListener(handler);
    cTextField.addActionListener(handler);

}

private class thehandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String string = "";

        if(discriminant == 0){
                string=String.format("Discriminant: " +discriminant +" x: " +x1, event.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(discriminant > 0){
            string=String.format("Discriminant: " +discriminant +" x: " +x1 +" x2: " +x2, event.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(discriminant < 0){
            string=String.format("Discriminant is under zero! No x found", event.getActionCommand());
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
    }

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at DiscriminantSoft.(DiscriminantSoft.java:17)
>       at tuna.main(tuna.java:5)

int a = Integer.parseInt(aTextField.getText()); is 17th row

Comment: This might sound stupid but have you initialised aTextfield?

Comment: can you show the full code?

Comment: private JTextField aTextField;

I also tried this:

String aValue = aTextField.getText();
int a = Integer.parseInt(aValue);

Comment: `private JTextField aTextField;`. but has it bee intialized?

Comment: post complete code..i think something related to initialization of textfield

Comment: Yes, PakkuDon you were right. I had initialized aTextField under that code.

Comment: I've posted the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the text of a text-field in the class context: when your text fields were not initialized.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(aTextField.getText()); 
                           // ^  text fields haven't yet initialized
int b = Integer.parseInt(bTextField.getText());
int c = Integer.parseInt(cTextField.getText());
int discriminant = (int)Math.pow((double)b, 2) - 4*a*c;
int x1 = (int)(-b + (double)Math.sqrt(discriminant) / 2*a);
int x2 = (int)(-b - (double)Math.sqrt(discriminant) / 2*a);

public DiscriminantSoft(){
///....... your code

   aTextField = new JTextField(3); // <---- you are initializing them here
   add(aTextField);
   bTextField = new JTextField(3);
   add(bTextField);
   cTextField = new JTextField(3);
    add(cTextField);
}
```

Whenever, a class is accessed, the field declared in the class context gets initialized first. If no initialization statement is give with `new` they are initialized to their default value: Objects are initialized to `null` as default.

Please read the [java language specification Chapter 12. Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.3)

Reading the text content of the text-fields in the class context doesn't actually make sense, so try reading text on action event or at least after initializing them. It is better to use `DocumentListener` with `JTextComponent`'s Document for generating event 
on text content changes.

Check out the official tutorial to know [how to use DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

try with toString() and please make sure that textfield input is not null

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(aTextField.getText().toString());
```

Comment: what was your input in aTextField?

Answer (score 0):

I posted something like this in the comments already but I figured I'd post it again in case OP wanted to mark this thread as answered. Sorry if this seems slightly narcissistic.

This code is throwing an NPE because you're calling getText() on a component that hasn't been initialised yet. You need to make sure that an object has been initialised before trying to invoke any methods on them.